# AD698 Half bridge LVDT circuit

Tags: bridge

I am trying to measure distance using LVDT sensor and AD698 IC. I don't have data relating the sensor I am using. I am simply tried to copy the distance measurement with device I already have. I matched the AC input and output of my system with the device that I already have. My input AC excitation is 5 Vp-p and 17 KHz. The output is alright. But I am facing problem in my DC output. The LVDT sensor that I am using is Half bridge type. I found this out after repeatedly checking sensor terminals. Circuit I used is exact one in page 6 of AD698 datasheet. http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD698.pdf

My DC supply is +/- 15 V. I want my voltage to swing from 0 - 5 V centered at 2.5 V. I tried varying resistors R1, R2 and R3. For this I put variable resistor in place of feedback resistor R2 and offset resistor R3 and AC voltage R1. Adjusting feedback resistor R2 increased/decreased offset voltage but also changed voltage swing accordingly. I managed to get 5 V swing but offset voltage is very high (~10.8 V, voltage swing 13.5 - 8.3 v). Adjusting offset resistor has no effect on the offset voltage. Referring to other forms, I connected 1M across +15 v and -AIN, and 1M across Gnd and -AIN but still did not change. I have tried many resistor values (8K, 3K, 20K) for R3 but offset voltage is unresponsive to R3. How do I change offset voltage ?

[image]

Comment: So, where do you have 0V (the midrail point on your supply) connected up to? Also pin 23 is unconnected?

Comment: 0 V is connected to Signal reference pin 21. According to datasheet, Pin23 (OFFSET1) is for -ve offset voltage and can be left alone if we don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

> Circuit I used is exact one in page 6 of AD698 datasheet.

No it isn't - you haven't got R4 connected in your circuit to pin 23. This affects the offsets and I don't see one diagram in the data sheet that has this resistor omitted. The data sheet says: -

> Selections of R3 and R4 permit a positive or negative output voltage
>   offset adjustment.

Having only one of these fitted means having a big offset!

Also, are you supplying a mid-point 0V to pin 21?

Comment: Mid-point 0V from 24-1515 converter is connected to pin 21 and Load resistor 3k connected across RL. Before, I left this one unconnected. Any suggestions as for calculating R4 ?

Comment: @sujan_014 I'm not familiar with this device so please refer to the data sheet as I would do.